# SQL: Controlling how many records get returned

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a film database with tables for movies, actors and directors. Each movie occupies a single row in the movie table. Almost all my queries require joins to other tables such that a query with LIMIT 50, offset 0 returns complete data for about 4 movies. Below is a sample query. How can I modify this to ensure getting data for exactly 10 movies back?

```
SELECT movie.id, movie.title, star.name, star.name_url, dir.name, 
       dir.name_url, genre.name, genre.name_url 
FROM movie 
        LEFT JOIN actor 
             ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS star 
             ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
        LEFT JOIN director 
             ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS dir 
             ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre_classification 
             ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre 
             ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
WHERE (movie.id > 0) 
ORDER BY movie.id 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

I am using PostgresSQL which probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go (untested):

```
SELECT movie.id, movie.title, star.name, star.name_url, dir.name, 
       dir.name_url, genre.name, genre.name_url 
FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie.id > 0 ORDER BY movie.id LIMIT 10) movie
        LEFT JOIN actor 
             ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS star 
             ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
        LEFT JOIN director 
             ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS dir 
             ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre_classification 
             ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre 
             ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
```

Edit: By putting all your conditions into the subselect, you cant control what data from the source table `movie` will be used for the JOIN. Performance wise, this also should be much faster.

Comment: That seems to work. Great. It's also fast. Thanks! Will accept when SO says I can.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, this one below is smarter: it don't use `SELECT *` and it optimizes performances (even if you don't have the problem) :

```
SELECT movie.id, movie.title, star.name, star.name_url, dir.name, 
       dir.name_url, genre.name, genre.name_url 
FROM movie 
        LEFT JOIN actor          ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS star ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
        LEFT JOIN director       ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS dir  ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre_classification ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre          ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
        JOIN (
            SELECT id
            FROM movie
            WHERE (id > 0) 
            ORDER BY id
            LIMIT 10
        ) AS sel ON (sel.id=movie.id)
ORDER BY movie.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still untested. Less performance wise than the answer given by tdk but more readable, the subselect can be written using the WITH statement:

```
WITH 
  sub_movie AS (
    SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie.id > 0 ORDER BY movie.id LIMIT 10
   )
SELECT
  sm.id,
  sm.title,
  star.name,
  star.name_url,
  dir.name,
  dir.name_url,
  genre.name,
  genre.name_url
FROM
  sub_movie sm
    LEFT JOIN actor 
         ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
    LEFT JOIN person AS star 
         ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
    LEFT JOIN director 
         ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
    LEFT JOIN person AS dir 
         ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
    LEFT JOIN genre_classification 
         ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
    LEFT JOIN genre 
         ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
```

I advise not to call PK column `id` but use `my_table_id` instead to be able to use smart join syntax like

```
    LEFT JOIN director USING (director_id)
```

Good luck.