# SQL: Controlling How Many Records Get Returned Part 2

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

This a follow up to the question I posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199719/sql-controlling-how-many-records-get-returned/12200855). Using the same kind of query, how do I make sure I get 10 movies back if there are restriction like 'genre.name = 'Classic Movies' and 'star.name = Humphrey Bogart.' To be clear, the query must return data for 10 movies regardless of what the filtering restrictions are.

```
SELECT movie.id, movie.title, star.name, star.name_url, dir.name, 
       dir.name_url, genre.name, genre.name_url 
FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie.id > 0 ORDER BY movie.id LIMIT 10) movie
        LEFT JOIN actor 
             ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS star 
             ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
        LEFT JOIN director 
             ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS dir 
             ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre_classification 
             ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre 
             ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're selecting a list of 10 movies from the database with this sub-select:

```
(SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie.id > 0 ORDER BY movie.id LIMIT 10) movie
```

If you're trying to filter down that list more using a WHERE clause outside that sub-select, you could potentially get *less than* those 10 rows, as not all 10 could match your criteria.  You could add that new criteria to the sub-select like so:

```
(SELECT * FROM movie m INNER JOIN genre_classification g on g.movie_id = m.id and g.name = 'Classic Movies' WHERE m.id > 0 ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 10) movie
```

This would do the same thing, but *only* give you (up to) 10 movies who had a matching genre of "Classic Movies".

This will, of course, still return more than 10 rows since you're `JOIN`ing in actors, directors, other genres, etc.  You should, however, have up to ten distinct movie IDs in the result set.

**Full Query:**

```
SELECT movie.id, movie.title, star.name, star.name_url, dir.name, 
       dir.name_url, genre.name, genre.name_url 
FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM movie m INNER JOIN genre_classification g on g.movie_id = m.id and g.name = 'Classic Movies' WHERE m.id > 0 ORDER BY m.id LIMIT 10) movie
        LEFT JOIN actor 
             ON (movie.id = actor.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS star 
             ON (actor.person_id = star.id) 
        LEFT JOIN director 
             ON (movie.id = director.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN person AS dir 
             ON (director.person_id = dir.id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre_classification 
             ON (movie.id = genre_classification.movie_id) 
        LEFT JOIN genre 
             ON (genre_classification.genre_id = genre.id)
```

Comment: It seemed that without the subselect, the LIMIT restricts the result to ten rows (inclusive of redundant information) which amounts to data for about 4 movies.

Comment: @MikeGirard - Yes, I now see from the other post why you're using the sub-select.  That's perfectly fine!  Just add your movie filtering to the sub-select and you'll be good to go..